# How to assign css background image from existing svg object?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, background-image

I try to assign a background-image from existing SVG object based on an example at

http://codepen.io/progers/pen/CAEks

```
// Short script to encode our SVG in base64
// This can be reversed using window.atob('base64')
var code = document.getElementById('code');
var demo = document.getElementById('demo');
var svg = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];

// Convert the SVG node to HTML.
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.appendChild(svg.cloneNode(true));

// Encode the SVG as base64
var b64 = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+window.btoa(div.innerHTML);
var url = 'url("' + b64 + '")';
code.innerHTML = 'Base64 CSS (for cross-browser compatibility)\n\nbackground-image: ' + url + ';';
demo.style.backgroundImage = url;
```

I created this

http://jsfiddle.net/bj0e063q/1/ jsfiddle.

The difference is that at codepen a static svg is used while I want to create it dynamic by code. Why does my example not work?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, it just wasn't running becuase the fiddle is already executing on window load, and because you need to define `window.socialSharing` before setting the svg up.

Edit:

Apparently, in order for it to work you need to set the background image on a div, and also set the `xmlns` attribute on the svg (Although in IE this attribute is added automatically, so you have to check for its existence):

```
svg.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");
```

Check this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ak92bf9n/).

Comment: Yes this was a mistake. But it should set background image

Comment: I don't see why setting an xmlns attribute would do anything at all.